# How can I silence user_target_xconfig pod install warnings

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've been having this warning in the console for years when I do pod install, is there a way to just silence those? The pods are external one where I have no control over their **podspec**

```
[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["AmazonPublisherServicesAdMobAdapter", "AmazonPublisherServicesSDK", "HyBid", "Banner", "Core", "FullScreen", "Native", "RewardedVideo", "MoPub-FacebookAudienceNetwork-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "MoPub-Verizon-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "mopub-ios-sdk", "Core", "MoPubSDK", "NativeAds"]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] has different values.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["AmazonPublisherServicesAdMobAdapter", "AmazonPublisherServicesSDK", "HyBid", "Banner", "Core", "FullScreen", "Native", "RewardedVideo", "MoPub-FacebookAudienceNetwork-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "MoPub-Verizon-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "mopub-ios-sdk", "Core", "MoPubSDK", "NativeAds"]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] has different values.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["AmazonPublisherServicesAdMobAdapter", "AmazonPublisherServicesSDK", "HyBid", "Banner", "Core", "FullScreen", "Native", "RewardedVideo", "MoPub-FacebookAudienceNetwork-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "MoPub-Verizon-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "mopub-ios-sdk", "Core", "MoPubSDK", "NativeAds"]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] has different values.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["AmazonPublisherServicesAdMobAdapter", "AmazonPublisherServicesSDK", "HyBid", "Banner", "Core", "FullScreen", "Native", "RewardedVideo", "MoPub-FacebookAudienceNetwork-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "MoPub-Verizon-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "mopub-ios-sdk", "Core", "MoPubSDK", "NativeAds"]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] has different values.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["AmazonPublisherServicesAdMobAdapter", "AmazonPublisherServicesSDK", "HyBid", "Banner", "Core", "FullScreen", "Native", "RewardedVideo", "MoPub-FacebookAudienceNetwork-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "MoPub-Verizon-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "mopub-ios-sdk", "Core", "MoPubSDK", "NativeAds"]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] has different values.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["AmazonPublisherServicesAdMobAdapter", "AmazonPublisherServicesSDK", "HyBid", "Banner", "Core", "FullScreen", "Native", "RewardedVideo", "MoPub-FacebookAudienceNetwork-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "MoPub-Verizon-Adapters", "MoPub", "Network", "mopub-ios-sdk", "Core", "MoPubSDK", "NativeAds"]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] has different values.
```

Comment: Hey, I am also facing similar issues.
Have you found any solution?